# Shell: aggregate several results (md5sum) into a single file

Tags: shell

This is my shell script snippet:

```
for f in $ENV_LOCATION/*.env
do
  basename=$(echo ${f##*/} | cut -f 1 -d '.')  #Extract base filename from a fullpath. Example: '/etc/secrets/t-secret.env' -> 't-secret'
  sort $f | md5sum > $temp/$basename.md5
done
```

As you can see I'm creating a new `*.md5` file into `$temp` folder for each file into `$ENV_LOCATION/*.env`.

I'd like to aggregate all these content files into a single one.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just a comment: The basename utility can strip filename suffixes, `basename pathname suffix`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moving the redirection should do the trick:

```
for f in $ENV_LOCATION/*.env
do
  basename=$(echo ${f##*/} | cut -f 1 -d '.')  #Extract base filename from a fullpath. Example: '/etc/secrets/t-secret.env' -> 't-secret'
  sort $f | md5sum
done > $temp/aggregate.md5
```

To keep `basename` output, here is a more useful version:

```
for f in $ENV_LOCATION/*.env
do
  basename $f .env
  sort $f | md5sum
done > $temp/aggregate.md5
```

Comment: basename can go as it's not used.

Comment: The issue with this, as with the code in the question, is that there is no longer any connection between the original filenames and the checksums.

Comment: @Kusalananda Wise comments indeed. TBH, I didn't even looked to what was inside the loop. Answer updated.